# Tizen IDE not loading

Tags: eclipse, tizen

I just installed Tizen SDK (with some problems so i had to use the SDK Image) but now it's installed correctly, i cant load the IDE (Eclipse).

It's stuck at 'Loading org.tizen.common'. I've tried everything but nothing helped.

Comment: Tizen SDK Version? Your system Configuration?
Can you restart your system and then start Tizen IDE? If it still doesn't work, post a screenshot of that screen.

Comment: Please report
    java -version

Comment: @rzr The newest, 1.8 build 64 i believe

Answer (score 3):

I also got this and the problem was that my android phone was connected to the PC when starting the IDE, disconnecting phone resolved the issue.

There's a related thread that pointed me to this problem (I would never guessed it):

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/if-android-phone-connected-pc-ide-start-loading-sometimes-freeze.

Answer (score 0):

After a reinstall and restart it worked.